# Past simple and past continuous in picture descriptions

Tags: past-tense

I found the following exercise in a workbook:

Choose the past simple or the past continuous:

...

5. In the exercise there .... a picture of three doctors who .... .

Answer key: was/sang

My question:  "Singing" is a progressive act, so why not using the past continuous?

Comment: Because "who singing" does not make sense!  You could have "... three doctors who sang" OR "... three doctors who ***were** singing*" OR "... three doctors singing".  But the third option omits "who" - which was already in the sentence!

Comment: ... Personally, I don't think that "three doctors who sang" sounds correct.  Additionally, when describing the contents of a picture or photo, it is quite common to use the *present* tense, because you are describing the scene **at the time the picture / photo was produced**.  So, if the picture showed you swimming, one might say "in the picture, I **am swimming** (present continuous).